# C++ Class Methods Definition Syntax

Tags: c++, class, syntax

In C++, it is sometimes considered good practice to declare your classes in a header file and define all the methods in a cpp file. I understand this, but a consequence of this seems to be that instead of having all of the class methods tabbed-in inside curly braces, they are just out in the open in the cpp file. **Is there any way to group the methods of a class together in the cpp file while still declaring them in a header file?** I like being able to collapse things in my IDE... I'd just get over it, but it's been a while since I've coded anything in C++ and I'm wondering if there's a way to do it that I just forgot about.

To be clear what I mean, here's an example:

test.h:

```cpp
class Testing {
public:
    Testing(int x);
    void print();
    int x;
};
```

test.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

// class Testing {
// public:
//     Testing(int x){
//         this->x = x;
//     }

//     void print(){
//         cout << this->x << endl;
//     }
// };

Testing::Testing(int x){
    this-> x = x;
}

void Testing::print(){
    cout << this->x;
}

int main(){
    Testing t(100);
    t.print();
}
```

I'd like to do what is commented above in test.cpp instead, but that doesn't work, right? (I think it'd be like declaring a new class distinct from the one in the header file?)

Comment: "..that doesn't work, right?" Yes, that's correct. Out-of-line method definitions (that is, those with bodies not appearing in the [class declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class)) must use that "C++::form". C++ is not Java or C# or anything else.

Comment: (The bigger syntax annoyances to me are that public/private cannot be applied to individual declarations.. or that qualifiers like 'static' or 'private' need not match between definitions and declarations or.. :|)

Comment: private is only present in the definition, how can it not match the declaration?

Comment: Are you aware you can have as many cpp files as you want?

Comment: @user2864740, I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

== h.h ==

```
namespace H_DEFS {
    class H {
    public:
       int A();
       int B();
    };
}
using namespace H_DEFS;
```

== h.cpp file ==

```
#include "h.h"
namespace H_DEFS {
   int H::A() { return 4;};
   int H::B() { return 5;};
}
```

== main.cpp ==

```
#include "h.h"
int main() {
   return H().A() + H().B();
}
```

but it's a weird idiom for other programmers to read just for the benefit of your IDE.

Comment: Alternatively simply put all the definitions for a class in a single cpp file, and everything else in a different cpp file. This is what every medium or large project does.

Comment: Thanks. I probably won't end up doing this. Like you said, it's a weird idiom for only the benefit of the IDE. I'm more just wondering what's the "right" way to do it, but it seems that the preferred thing to do is to get over it? or just have one file per class? What do you prefer?